# 'ServiceCollection' Does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I'm trying to create a Discord bot in C#, and the code I have here produces an exception with following message: *'ServiceCollection' Does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments*

```
_services = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddSingleton(_client)
            .AddSingleton(_commands)
            .BuildServiceProvider();
```

The references if that helps

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Services.Description;
using Discord;
using Discord.Commands;
using Discord.WebSocket;
```

I am quite a beginner in programming, So any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The error code says something about a `ServiceCollector` but your code only mentions a `ServiceCollection`, is this correct and if so where is that code?. Also can you add the usings of this file? In general try to ask a question as complete as possible

Comment: Oh sorry, I made a typo, meant to say Collection there. Also added the references.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should replace `System.Web.Services.Description` namespace with `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`

Firstly, you need to install `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` nuget package, and then include it in namespace references

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
```

It provides another `ServiceCollection` class, so your code does not throw a compilation error anymore

```
new ServiceCollection();
```

Comment: my suggestion is based on assumption that you are using some version of .net core, and not .net framework